# How to remove "Algorithm #" caption prefix but keep list of algorithms?

Tags: table-of-contents, captions, algorithms

I am using the `algorithm`-package and would like to name my algorithms without any generated prefix. So I would like to remove "Algorithm #" as prefix from my caption, but still keep the list of algorithms listing the captions.

I have two minimal working examples, each one doing only a part of the required job.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{algorithm}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption*{My Algorithm}
\end{algorithm}

\listofalgorithms

\end{document}
```

This removes the caption prefix, but the algorithm is not included in the list.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{algorithm}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\floatname{algorithm}{}
\caption{My Algorithm}
\end{algorithm}

\listofalgorithms

\end{document}
```

This removes the caption prefix partially, (the number "1" still remains), but the algorithm is included in the list.

Comment: What about the number in the list of algorithms?

Comment: @egreg After using the solution with `labelformat=empty` the prefix is removed, but the number stays in the list-of-algorithms. Which is exactly what I want :)

Comment: I don't think it makes much sense: if the number is missing next to the caption, you can't refer to algorithms by numbers and those in the list point to nothing. If you want to remove them, just add `\renewcommand{\thealgorithm}{}` after `\usepackage{algorithm}`.

Comment: Ok thanks. I've just tried it, it looks like there is something missing :-) ... but I keep it for the moment, now I know how to tweak that bit!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's one possibility, defining a format with the help of the `caption` package:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{algorithm}

\DeclareCaptionFormat{myformat}{#3}
\captionsetup[algorithm]{format=myformat}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{My Algorithm}
\end{algorithm}
\listofalgorithms

\end{document}
```

[image]

As **egreg** has pointed out, the `caption` package already offers the `empty` format, so there's no need to define a new one:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{algorithm}

\captionsetup[algorithm]{labelformat=empty}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{My Algorithm}
\end{algorithm}
\listofalgorithms

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

In the second MWE, add the algorithm to the list explicitely using `\addcontentsline`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{algorithm}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption*{My Algorithm}
\addcontentsline{loa}{algorithm}{My Algorithm}
\end{algorithm}

\listofalgorithms

\end{document}
```